# Is Redshift translating "dbo" schema to "public" schema?

Tags: redshift

We have a strange issue which has appeared in the last couple of days.

We have two Amazon Redshift clusters. One cluster has our production workload, and the other cluster has our non-production workload. There are 4 copies of the same database. 1 production copy, and 3 copies in non-production.

In the last few days, data extracts began failing in our non-production environment. Upon further investigation, we see that the error is:

> ERROR: schema "dbo" does not exist

So, upon closer inspection. Sure enough, the query is using `dbo` as the schema and there is no `dbo` schema in the database. All of the tables exist in the `public` schema. This would make sense if this didn't work for months prior to this event, and is actually still working in production.

The original (simplified) query looks like this:

```
select top 1 * from [dbo].[my_table];
```

In this case, `dbo` does not exist in any environment. `my_table` exists in the `public` schema. However, the above query works fine still on our production cluster, while it now fails, with the invalid schema error on our non-production cluster.

I also tried changing the query to:

```
select top 1 * from "dbo"."my_table";
```

I get the same results. Works fine in production. Does not work in non-production. In fact, if I try `select top 1 * from "public"."my_table";` I get the same results (as `dbo`) in production, and the query works as expected in non-production. And, if I try `select top 1 * from "asdf"."my_table"` it fails universally.

I also checked the Redshift user's search path, in case that had something to do with it. In each environment the search patch is default: `$user,public`

I confirmed on all the databases that the `dbo` schema does NOT exist, and that all the tables are in `public`. I also checked the cluster version and update history. I identified that the non-production cluster is running version `1.0.44126`, and the production cluster is running version `1.0.43931`. The extracts did start failing after this update. I cannot find any reference to version `1.0.44126` online and have no idea what has changed here. (C'mon AWS, update your documentation!)

I can't find any reference to Redshift translating `dbo` to `public` or any other related feature that might do that.

I am able to reproduce the issue by issuing the following two statements:

`create table public.test_table ( test integer );`

`select * from dbo.test_table;`

I can also do: `drop table dbo.test_table;`

It will work fine on my `1.0.43931` cluster, and fail on the `1.0.44126` cluster. Clearly there is a mechanism here which is treating these two schemas names the same.

**Why does the query `select top 1 * from "dbo"."my_table";` work at all when the actual table is `"public"."my_table"`?**

**Why did it stop working all the sudden in version 1.0.44126 (if that is the case)?**

Comment: "dbo" is the default schema for SQL Server. Is any jiggery-pokery going on in moving data out of a SQL Server database (still in use, or maybe stopped in the distant past)? What does version control tell you? (cough)

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' You are correct. And we did consider this. And yes, the data being populated in to redshift is part of an ETL process from SQL server databases. And the redshift database used to run on SQL server, that is why we errantly had references to "dbo" in our code. However, this doesn't seem to be related to anything here. The only change I know happened that I have identified is a new version of Redshift. The non working cluster is 1.0.44126 and the one that is working is 1.0.43931. I did identify that the problem did occur after this update (I previously missed this).

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I cannot find any reference to version 1.0.44126 online yet.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I revised the post with this new information, and also showed that I can easily reproduce this behavior by creating a table in the public schema and querying it in the dbo schema.

Comment: No version control then? You can't track who and when wrote these queries that use a schema that never existed in your database?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the exact same situation.  The thing I can't determine is how these "dbo.XXX" queries ever worked before as there has never been a dbo schema.
An ugly (but effective) quick solution was to create a dbo schema and create views for each table in public, effectively acting as aliases.

Comment: but how and why these queries were ever written in the first place? Surely you have a version control where you can track who wrote them.